# Only first parameter passed to SOAP server PHP and yii

Tags: php, web-services, soap, yii

I'm using yii to build a soap web service. Im experiencing a strange issue.

I create the params eg:

```
  $new=array('x' => 1,
             'y' => 2,
             'z' => 3);
```

Then i send it, the soap server only receives the first value in the array.

Soap server:

```
<?php
 class testController extends CController
{
    public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            'new'=>array(
                'class'=>'CWebServiceAction',
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param int $x
     * @param int $y
     * @param int $z
     * @return returnParams
     * @soap
     **/
    public function test($x,$y,$z)
    {
        Yii::log("$x : $y : $z", CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR);
        $returnParam = new returnParams();
        $returnParam->x = $x;
        $returnParam->y = $y;
        $returnParam->z = $z;
        return $returnParam;

    }

}
?>
```

The returnParams class as follows

```
    <?php

  class returnParams{
        /**
        * @var int
        * @soap
        **/
  public $x;

        /**
        * @var int
        * @soap
        **/
  public $y;

        /**
        * @var int
        * @soap
        **/
  public $z;

 }
```

So its pretty basic, recieve the info and send it right back.

Here is the response

```
object(stdClass)#2 (9) {
  ["x"]=>
  int(1)
  ["y"]=>
  NULL
  ["z"]=>
  NULL
```

The log shows $y and $z as empty. Can anyone see what im doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry Guys

Figured it out, I was passing an array where I should have been passing the separate variables.

Apologies if I wasted anyone's time.

Comment: Wish i could. I don’t have the reputation to mark it as answered, only after 8 hours. It was the first thing i tried.

Comment: In that case, just post the answer. You can mark it as accepted after 8 hours.

Comment: Posting details of how you were posting to the SOAP server and how you resolved the issue would likely be useful for those researching this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i stated the answer is as follows.

I was creating an array and sending that to the soap server

```
    $new=array('x' => 1,
             'y' => 2,
             'z' => 3);

$response = $client->test($new);
```

Where i should have been doing

```
$x = 1;
$y = 2;
$z = 3;
$response = $client->test($x,$y,$z);
```

Thanks for the assistance.